# device not loading into bootloader

Tags: bootloader, fastboot, micromax-a110

I am trying to boot my rooted android device into bootloader to unlock it. I have tried following commands but none is working.

```
adb reboot-bootloader  
adb reboot bootloader
```

Even when trying to boot into bootloader using device buttons, I get two modes:

```
recovery mode  
factory mode
```

but none of the mode contains any option for fastboot or bootloader. I am not getting any way to load bootloader. Please help me with this issue.

I tried to do it with fastboot also. But following command is not listing any device

```
fastboot devices
```

Comment: What device are you using exactly?

Comment: Micromax A110. lsusb is showing HTC (High Tech Computer Corp.)